# Compton wavelength And universe expansion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, universe, space-expansion

I'd like to ask stupid question. As I understand the wavelength of photons increase in time due to universe expansion. And it seems that Compton wavelength of particles does not changes in the same way since it depends only on the particle's rest mass. Why it happens? The wave nature of particles with and without mass is different?

Comment: The electromagnetic field doesn't have a rest mass and it's not the rest mass that gets reduced by the expansion, but the energy-momentum of the field. If you were to do the same with a massive field, its energy-momentum would also get smaller, until it runs out of momentum and then stops completely. This massive particle horizon is simply shorter than the massless photon horizon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the case. The conformal transformation of the metric $g_{ab}~\rightarrow~\Omega^2g_{ab}$ transforms the line element as
$$
ds^2~\rightarrow~ds^2~=~\Omega^2(du^2~-~dx^2~-~dy^2~-~dz^2).
$$
Then for the case that $du~=~\Omega^{-1}dt$ we have the metric
$$
ds^2~=~dt^2~-~\Omega^2(dx^2~+~dy^2~+~dz^2),
$$
that is the de Sitter spacetime metric for $\Omega^2~=~exp(t\sqrt{\Lambda/3})$. This is a time dependent conformal spacetime; it is over all conformal, but with a timelike direction that has the spatial surface expanding exponentially. This is the sort of cosmology we are approximately in and as time goes on will converge to this metric completely.

For a photon its wavelength scales with the expansion of space. We can think of a photon of a given wavelength $\lambda$ in a region of space as being in a cavity. As one photon leaves another enters. Then the wavelength expands with the space $\lambda~\propto~a$ for $a$ the scale factor, and as energy is $E = h\nu$ $= hc/\lambda$ the energy scales inversely with the scale factor $E~\propto~a^{-1}$. The energy density, energy per volume, then scales as $\rho~\propto~a^{-4}$.

Matter does not do this. A classical particle has a fixed mass, and thus energy by $E~=~mc^2$. As a result the density of matter particles scales as $\rho~\propto~a^{-3}$. This does not scale in the same manner. A matter particle has a Compton wavelength $\lambda_c~=~\frac{\hbar}{mc}$, but just as with the classical particle the mass does not scale with the expansion. Hoyle and Bondi proposed an idea that particles would be created as the universe expands. While this would not cause the Compton wavelength to change it would result in an overall matter distribution that would scale as does radiation.

Comment: This is only so if the masses are gravitationally bound, though. Two masses that are not bound will retreat from each other, that retreat will be at ever faster velocities.